# Can I control CSS selection for :hover on nested elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure a solution out to the following. I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="width:50em; height:10em">
    <span class='rating-5 rating-span'>
        <span class='rating-4 rating-span'>
            <span class='rating-3 rating-span'>
                <span class='rating-2 rating-span'>
                    <span class='rating-1 rating-span'>
                        <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
                    </span>
                    <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
                </span>
                <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
             </span>
             <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
         </span>
         <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
     </span>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
div.rating-star{
    display:inline-block;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    /*border:solid thin black;*/
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

div.rating-star.unselected {
    background-image: url(star.jpg);   
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.rating-span:hover div.rating-star {
    background-image: url(hover.jpg);   
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The idea is that, if you hover over a star, all the stars from the left will light up.
However, what *actually* happens is that all of the stars light up, wherever you hover.

Now it's clear to me that this is because my :hover selector is selecting the outermost span. My question is this: in the case of the :hover selector, there is a determination of which element is being hovered over. In the case where that element contains other elements (of the same type), is there a way to stipulate *which* element should be selected. In this case it would be the lowest possible one.

I appreciate that I could do this quite simply with Javascript; I'm just hoping that there's a pure CSS solution to it.

**UPDATE**
Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MkJmj/1/
It's slightly modified to use absolute urls to the images, but otherwise identical

Comment: This would be great to solve with CSS alone. +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: Can you provide a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I think I have an idea, but I'm not sure until I can test it (and I can't be bothered to go looking for star icons to test with).

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it's not valid to nest `div`s inside `span`s - you may as well turn everything into `span` instead.

Comment: Not posting this as an answer, just something you might like to look into: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/689/Pure-CSS-Star-Rating-System I think this solution is *much* cleaner than what you are attempting to do.

Comment: If highlighting right to left rather than left to right, it would be easy and clean, using something like 

`.rating-star:hover, .rating-star:hover ~ .rating-star`

and dropping the unseemly nested stuff. Unfortunately there's no "sibling preceeded by" selector, and unlikely to ever be one.

Comment: @TheKaneda: Actually, in that case, `.rating-span:hover > div.rating-star` is sufficient.

Comment: @Dancrumb: Not without the nested HTML which was the first thing to go in my tests. ;-)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this without using JavaScript? I don't see any form buttons or links, so surely you're *already* using JavaScript to submit the result via AJAX when a star is clicked? If you're not using JavaScript to submit the result, how are you doing it?

Comment: The fiddle appears to be broken here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A Pure CSS Solution

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alecgorge/Sw5Ym/

This is a pure CSS solution. I would recommend changing the HTML, but this was a fun exercise.  Here is what I changed:

```
div.rating-star{
    display:inline-block;

...

.rating-span:hover div.rating-star {
```

to

```
div.rating-star{
    display:block;
    float:right;

...

.rating-span:hover > div.rating-star {
```

### A better solution

By changing the `div`'s to `span`'s you have valid HTML (although a bit messy), and you can have a fully IE 7+ compatible solution: http://jsfiddle.net/alecgorge/FEHuw/

Make sure you resize the window to show all the stars on one line. Once the star image is smaller, the `span`'s can be smaller and things will work better.

Comment: Thanks for that solution; I'll need to change my invalid HTML anyway, so I guess I won't end up using this one... but kudos for finding a solution!

Comment: this fiddle also seems to be broken :/

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your HTML, since it was both invalid and unwieldy (not to mention difficult to target easily with CSS selectors). And, with that modified HTML, the CSS (below) seems to work as you want. Though it's tested only in Chromium 14, older browsers will almost certainly not quite work. Nor Internet Explorer (at all, at a guess):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
    <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
    <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
    <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
    <div class='rating-star unselected'></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div:hover div.rating-star:hover ~ div.rating-star {
    background-image: url(http://danrumney.co.uk/images/star.jpg);   
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MkJmj/3/).

Comment: That's a delightful solution. Turns out that MSIE doesn't like the background-size at all, so I may be on a hiding to nothing. However, I really like this solution... very neat.