# Selecting only immediately hovered element in CSS for nested elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have a collection of nested comments. My goal is to display a 'reply' option when hovering each comment separately. This means that I don't want the 'reply' option to show up for parent/sibling/children of the comment I am hovering.

The only similar question I have found is: [Can I control CSS selection for :hover on nested elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057666/can-i-control-css-selection-for-hover-on-nested-elements) I am not even sure his needs are the same, and additionally the fiddles don't seem to work.

I have prepared a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls50sLpc/1/) so you better see what I mean:

```css
.comment {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.text {} .comment:hover > .reply {
  display: inline-block;
}
.reply {
  display: none;
}
.children-comments {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <a class="text">wohoo</a>
  <a class="reply">reply</a>
  <div class="children-comments">
    <div class="comment">
      <a class="text">wohoo</a>
      <a class="reply">reply</a>
      <div class="children-comments">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <a class="text">wohoo</a>
      <a class="reply">reply</a>
      <div class="children-comments">
        <div class="comment">
          <a class="text">wohoo</a>
          <a class="reply">reply</a>
          <div class="children-comments">
            <div class="comment">
              <a class="text">wohoo</a>
              <a class="reply">reply</a>
              <div class="children-comments">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <a class="text">wohoo</a>
      <a class="reply">reply</a>
      <div class="children-comments">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that using `>` in the selector does work to ignore the sibling elements but it still selects the parent elements. In other words, no matter which comment you hover, the parent of them all will always show the 'reply' option.

Can this be done with CSS only at all? I'm open to js solutions but I'd be more than happy if there was a CSS only solution.

Comment: Done, I didn't want to clutter the question with useless boilerplate, but point understood :)

Comment: You could still do that. Just use snippets and check the hide by default option. That way your code will be in question and the boilerplate won't show up unless expanded :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best option would be to change the markup a little bit and add a wrapper:

```
<div class="comment">
  <div class="content">   <!-- Here -->
    <a class="text">wohoo</a>
    <a class="reply">reply</a>
  </div>
```

By adding a `div` wrapper for the content, you can target comments individually using `.content:hover > .reply`

Example:

```css
.comment {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.text {}

.content:hover > .reply {
  display: inline-block;
}

.reply {
  display: none;
}

.children-comments {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="content">
    <a class="text">wohoo</a>
    <a class="reply">reply</a>
  </div>
  <div class="children-comments">
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="content">
        <a class="text">wohoo</a>
        <a class="reply">reply</a>
      </div>
      <div class="children-comments">
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="content">
            <a class="text">wohoo</a>
            <a class="reply">reply</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="children-comments">
          <div class="comment">
            <div class="content">
              <a class="text">wohoo</a>
              <a class="reply">reply</a>
            </div>
            <div class="children-comments">
              <div class="comment">
                <div class="content">
                  <a class="text">wohoo</a>
                  <a class="reply">reply</a>
                </div>
                <div class="children-comments">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment">
        <div class="content">

          <a class="text">wohoo</a>
          <a class="reply">reply</a>
          <div class="children-comments">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The content wrapper would expand to the area of the actual content of the comment (which makes the most sense).

However, you could also make the wrapper expand to the entire comment block as well (more than just the comment's content) by using positioning styles. For example:

```
/* OPTIONAL - These style changes make the content
 * wrapper cover the entire comment block.
 */
.comment {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.comment .content {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

It just depends on your desired behavior.

([jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fcyfscu8/))

Comment: I'm trying to get the link to play with your solution in fiddle. I'm failing to find a link there. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: brilliant, actually that 'additional' div already exists in my original markup so awesome! :) Thanks!

Comment: @mezod You can run the snippet inline with my answer, or, you can use this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fcyfscu8/

Answer (score 1):

**without** changing your markup, instead hovering the parent `.comment`, you can hover the adjacent sibling(using `+`) `.text` (because it always be there)

```css
.comment {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.text {
  display:inline-block
}
.text:hover + .reply {
  display: inline-block;
}
.reply {
  display: none;
}
.children-comments {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <a class="text"> wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo </a>
  <a class="reply">reply</a>
  <div class="children-comments">
    <div class="comment">
      <a class="text">wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo </a>
      <a class="reply">reply</a>
      <div class="children-comments">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <a class="text">wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo </a>
      <a class="reply">reply</a>
      <div class="children-comments">
        <div class="comment">
          <a class="text"> wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo </a>
          <a class="reply">reply</a>
          <div class="children-comments">
            <div class="comment">
              <a class="text"> wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo  </a>
              <a class="reply">reply</a>
              <div class="children-comments">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <a class="text"> wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo  wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo wohoo </a>
      <a class="reply">reply</a>
      <div class="children-comments">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is indeed a very smart alternative. Unfortunately for me, my real markup isn't that 'simple' and this solution wouldn't work exactly as I'd expect it to. But your approach just gave me lots of insight and ideas, so thank your for the time you took to reply :)

Comment: So next time show the full code, to help you better, otherwise we are just giving you bad insights for your real problem.

Comment: I don't think there's a need to be rude here. I posted a simplified version because I was searching for a relatively markup-independent solution with css selectors. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: Wasn't my intention to be rude, sorry if sounded rude to you :) Just trying to help you understand that is better to have the real code to have a correct answer :)